# How to filter numeric values when indexing a text field in solr

Tags: search, solr, indexing

My question is: How can I remove numeric values in text field?

Eg. "ABC COMPANY 
SUITE 39 
165 MICHIGAN AVE
LANSING MI 48909"

In order to get the folowing terms: "ABC | COMPANY | SUITE | MICHIGAN | AVE | LANSING | MI"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PatternReplaceFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceFilterFactory.html).

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
```